# block user from disable GPRS/GPS

Tags: java, android, gps, android-settings

Is there a way to block a user from disabling the GPRS / GPS?

As I know We can block a user from access the system setting, but a user can swip from up and enable/disable the options.

Comment: @Nisha ya you are right, let we research on this, let we see what should we find okaay??

Comment: Seems like a contravention of the users' privacy.  Is there a good reason for doing this?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne good != ethical

Comment: @AnthonyHorne I know it's disturb users' privacy.But having android app for salesman,admin don't want to allow any access rather then designed app even not access to system settings. It's crucial but needy. That's why.

Comment: For enterprises, you may be able to "enforce" device policies.  See: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1408902?hl=en

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Thanks for link. But still not getting how to block GPS access. Can you describe some in detail?

Comment: Friends even it's feasible in rooted phone? if possible, please post your answer.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel mitr, you can do it using device admin I think, you must need to make device admin, I hope you remember it.

Comment: @DASA, Really not remember. can you describe some more in detail?

Comment: nop, you must need to remember it, for Spy app I hae did it if you remember buddy

Comment: As a start, you can enable "Enable application auditing" which should allow you to monitor the setting.  Also, according to https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/190930?hl=en you can use the policy to "locate" the phone, so you can keep track of the location anyway.